# Regular expression: 'func("aaa", "bbb");' - find "aaa" and "bbb"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:
`'some text........ func("aaa", "bbb");  more text..'`

How can I get "aaa" and "bbb" using regex? (group)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/(\(\w+,\s*\w+\))/`

Comment: Since people are spoon-feeding today, I am adding my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
r=/.*func\("([^&"]*)", *"([^&"]*)"\).*/
s='some text........ func("aaa", "bbb");  more text..'
result = r.exec(s)
val1 = result[1]
val2 = result[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get them with a regex like

```
func\("([^"]+)",\s*"([^"]+)"\);
```

Here,

- `func\("` - matches `func(` literally
- `([^"]+)` - matches and captures into Group 1 1 or more characters other than a `"`
- `",\s*"` - quote, comma, optional whitespace and a quote
- `([^"]+)` - matches and captures 1 or more characters other than `"`
- `"\);` - literally matches `");`

The `[^"]+` can be replaced with `[^"\n]` if you needn't matching newlines.

See demo:

```js
var rx = /func\("([^"]+)",\s*"([^"]+)"\);/g;
s='some text........ func("aaa", "bbb");  more text.. func("ccc", "ddd");';
while ((m=rx.exec(s))!== null) {
  document.write("Input: " + m[0] + "<br/>");
  document.write("First: " + m[1] + "<br/>");
  document.write("Second: " + m[2] + "<br/>");
}
```